# Do 'language chain' methods in mocha actually do anything?

Tags: mocha.js

It seems that methods like '.to', '.be' and '.is' in mocha don't have any real purpose other than readability, and that they are built to be essentially invisible to the computer. Is this correct, and can they be left out?

Comment: I quick look over the docs suggests that at least `is... ` methods are assertions, meaning they probably throw if violated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the interesting question!

In short, the answer to your question is **yes, they can be left out** and your assertion will have the same meaning.

For example, all of these should pass:

```
expect({"ok":"hello"}).is.not.undefined;
expect({"ok":"hello"}).to.not.undefined;
expect({"ok":"hello"}).be.not.undefined;
expect({"ok":"hello"}).be.is.to.be.not.undefined;
expect({"ok":"hello"}).to.to.to.to.to.not.to.to.to.to.undefined;
expect({"ok":"hello"}).not.undefined;
```

I was curious how these functions were implemented, and since I was using WebStorm I could just ctrl + click on one of these methods to jump to it's source (which even though I was using mocha jumped into a file called *unit.js*. The source's whitespace was condensed, but after copy / pasting into a new js file and doing ctrl + alt + L to reformat the code was very nice and easy to read. Below I have included the implementation for the three functions you specifically asked about.

```
get to() {
      return this
    }

get be() {
      return h.call(this, this.equal)
    }

get is() {
      return h.call(this, this.equal)
    }
```

I hope that helps!